# Функция выводящая строку и файл, в котором она вызвана

Tags: c++, visual-studio

Как написать на С++ функцию, которая выводит строку и название файла, в котором она вызвана.

Answer (score 3):

Если правильно понял, то Вас интересует вот это:

```
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ cat c1.cpp
#include <stdio.h>

// HERE() это просто тест __FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __LINE__
#define HERE(msg) (printf("%s: in %s [%s line %d]\n",(msg), \
                          __FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __LINE__ ))

void test_func (const char *msg)
{
  HERE(msg);
}


int main()
{
  test_func("You are here");
}
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ g++ c1.cpp
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$ ./a.out 
You are here: in test_func [c1.cpp line 9]
avp@avp-ubu1:hashcode$
```

Эта штука (`__FILE__`, `__LINE__` и т.п.) называется [Standard Predefined Macros](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Standard-Predefined-Macros.html)