# __line__ номер линии кода

Tags: c#

Не первый раз приходится писать

```
log1(613,"msg");
log1(614,"msg");
```

В с++ есть классная штука `__LINE__` на [www.cprogramming.com](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/preprocessor/__LINE__.html)
и [с++ ф-ция логирования](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/413794/%d0%a4%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%8f%d1%89%d0%b0%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%be%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%b8-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d0%b2-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0/413798#413798)
, есть ли простое решение для с# логирования именно строки, которая выполняется?

Comment: Нашёл на en so [асоциация](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/696218/do-line-file-equivalents-exist-in-c)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Легко! Нужно воспользоваться «магическим» атрибутом [`[CallerLineNumber]`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.runtime.compilerservices.callerlinenumberattribute?view=netframework-4.7.1), который заставляет компилятор подставить номер строки.

Например, так:

```
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
```

```
static int GetLineNumber([CallerLineNumber] int line = -1) => line;
```

Пример использования:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Этот код находится в строке " + GetLineNumber());
    }

    static int GetLineNumber([CallerLineNumber] int line = -1) => line;
}
```

В вашем случае я бы объявил функцию `log1` так:

```
void log1(string message, [CallerLineNumber] int line = -1)
{
    if (line != -1) { ... }
}
```

и вызывал бы просто

```
log1("msg");
```

---

[Другие магические атрибуты](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/caller-information): `[CallerMemberName]` (очень полезен для реализации `INotifyPropertyChanged`!) и `[CallerFilePath]`.

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. для работы атрибутов `[CallerLineNumber]` нужен .Net 4, хочу заметить что есть и другие решения, среди которых рефлексия. Недостаток рефлексии - если решение не debug (нет отладочной информации) то не будет имени файла, и номера линии. Если есть обфускация - то этот метод вообще не имеет смысла.

```
void log1(string message){
StackTrace st = new StackTrace(new StackFrame(true));
Console.WriteLine(" Stack trace for current level: {0}", st.ToString());
StackFrame sf = st.GetFrame(0);
Console.WriteLine(" File: {0}", sf.GetFileName());
Console.WriteLine(" Method: {0}", sf.GetMethod().Name);
Console.WriteLine(" Line Number: {0}", sf.GetFileLineNumber());
Console.WriteLine(" Column Number: {0}", sf.GetFileColumnNumber());
// ...
}
```

Взято с [en so](https://stackoverflow.com/a/696230/5727271)

Comment: Не нужен свежий .NET. Достаточно объявить свой атрибут с правильным полным именем типа.

Comment: На XP доступен .NET 4, а для него есть это:
 [Microsoft BCL Portability Pack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl/)

Comment: В Net 2.0 в System.Runtime.CompilerServices нету перечисленных атрибутов.

Comment: @Андрей не хватает дискового места, что б его установить.

Comment: Что у вас за ПК такие, что нет лишних 10 МБ? Выпилите из винды что-нибудь "ненужное"

Comment: Папка v4.0 у меня весит 200Мб, а инсалятор standalone требует почти гиг.

Comment: @nick_n_a говорю же, можно объявить свой. Именно вот в этом самом пространстве имен.

Comment: Компилятору не важно в какой сборке атрибут объявлен, он смотрит только на полное имя типа.

Comment: @PavelMayorov Т.е. это "недокументированые возможности"? Хорошо, попробую.