# C# и атрибуты параметров функций для значений по умолчанию

Tags: c#, ado.net

Можно ли передать в функцию параметр со значением по умолчанию типа вызывающего класса через атрибут? Что-то типа:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter, Inherited = true)]
public class CallerTypeAttribute : ...
{
...
}

class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string sourceFilePath = "",
    [CallerType] Type type = null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(type.FullName);
    }
}

class MyClassParent
{
    public MyClassParent()
    {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass(); //// должен напечатать в консоли  MyClassParent
    }
}
```

Comment: А что такое "вызывающий класс"?

Comment: class MyClassParent
    {
        ...
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
    }

Comment: а чего вы хотите этим добиться?

Comment: Приведите пример поподробнее, пару примеров вызова и что в каждом случае должно получиться

Comment: Хочу в экземпляре MyClass знать, из какого класса вызван его конструктор.

Comment: Классы ничего не вызывают, код выполняется только в методах. Вы хотите узнать, к какому классу принадлежит этот метод?

Comment: Уточнил в вопросе. Классы ничего не вызывают, но если в методе родительского класса вызван конструктор целевого класса, я хочу в этом конструкторе знать, какой тип его позвал. Причем через параметр со значением по умолчанию, по аналогии с приведенным в примере атрибутом CallerFilePath для параметра sourceFilePath

Comment: Может это https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763539/line-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0 поможет?

Comment: Всего лишь для статистики. Увы, исправить код во всех местах, где вызывается конструктор, и передавать тип как параметр нет желания.

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать, создав стектрейс вызова:

```
class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        var st = new StackTrace();
        creatorType = st.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().DeclaringType;
    }

    Type creatorType;

    public Type GetCreatorType() => creatorType;
}
```

Мы получаем первый стекфрейм (нулевой - это наш текущий метод, а первый - это метод, который его вызывает), берем из него метод и определяем тип, в котором метод объявлен.

Тестируем:

```
class A
{
    public MyClass CreateMy()
    {
        return new MyClass();
    }
}

class B
{
    public MyClass MyClass = new MyClass();
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new A();
        var b = new B();
        var my1 = new MyClass();
        var my2 = a.CreateMy();
        var my3 = b.MyClass;
        Console.WriteLine(my1.GetCreatorType()?.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(my2.GetCreatorType()?.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(my3.GetCreatorType()?.Name);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Вывод:

```
Program
A
B
```

Comment: А в release mode работает?

Comment: @VladD, выводит `Program Program Program`, подозреваю, что в релизе классов A и B фактически и нет. Но другого способа я не знаю. Вообще затея автора сомнительна

Comment: Это ведь не через атрибут. И как-то же реализован "System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath".

Comment: CallerFilePath это фишка компилятора! Напишите свой компилятор, который будет поддерживать ваш атрибут