# Красивая обертка для try-catch в C#

Tags: c#

Вопрос не про то, как красиво программировать, чтобы этот вопрос не возникал, а про красивую обертку над `try-catch`.

```
try
{

}
catch 
{
    // здесь ничего нет
}
```

- эта хорошая штука, но но занимает много места, хотелось бы, чтобы умещалось в один блок, но выполняло тот же функционал

Делаю кусок кода, который подстраховочный и вообще не достоин, чтобы на него уделяли большое внимание (сейчас уделяю такое внимание только на будущее, потому, что уже не раз задумывался над этой issue, ну и чтоб отдохнуть). Он не стоит того, чтобы делать рефакторинг, чтоб изящничать. Нужно просто и быстро поставить `try`, но хотелось бы чтобы это выглядело красиво. Если там что-то не сработает, то ничего страшного, но хотелось бы еще, чтобы это не повлекло за собой появление Exception-а уже в важных местах, поэтому вопрос про `try-catch`.

Есть вариант сделать метод:

```
private void Try(Action codeBlock)
{
    try
    {
        codeBlock?.Invoke();
    } 
    catch 
    {
    } 
}
```

тогда вызов будет в одну строчку, но этот вариант не на 100% нравится:

- кажется не красивым вызов `Try( ()=>DoWork() );`, хотелось бы что-то попроще, без наворотов
- можно в аргумент передать вызов метода напрямую `Try(MethodCall)`, это уже выглядит получше, но тогда в моем конкретном случае придется разбивать этот подстраховочный и второстепенный по важности метод на многие части, например, если случай такой:

  ```
  private static void EnsureSomethingWhichFailsAnyway(Someting input)
  {
      try
      {
          foreach (var x in input.GetAllX())
          {
              DoSmallThing(x);
              try
              {
                  x.SetPropertyValue = PossibleValues.BigValue;
              }
              catch { }
          }
      } catch { }
      try
      {
          foreach (var y in input.GetllY())
          {
              try
              {
                  y.Validate(StaticVars.A, StaticVars.B, StaticVars.C);
              }
              catch { }
          }
      }
      catch { }
  }
  ```
- то есть, если разбивать такой метод на подметоды для вызова типа `Try(MethodCall)` то игра не будет стоить свеч.
- можно ли как-то поместить в `using`?
- может быть нет идеального решения, тогда интересно просто услышать конструктивные мысли.

Спасибо!

Comment: Тихие исключения опасно использовать, потому что... в итоге очень сложно отыскать ошибку. Хорошо бы вернуть и обработать хотя бы boolean. Какая у вас цель на самом деле?

Comment: @nick_n_a, спасибо, полезно! Но в моем случае вопрос про то, когда код такой что не на что по сути не влияет.

Comment: Я так и не понял, чем плох способ, который вы предлагаете (блок `try` поместить в метод `Try`, в который передается делегат).

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, спасибо!  - тут дело такое, что сам метод внутри разбит на `try-catch` на каждый чих. Разбивать на подметоды - игра не стоит свеч.

Comment: Если обратиться к книге Роберта Мартина 'Чистый код', то он пишет про вариант с отдельным методом https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwZiI.png

Comment: Во впервых пустой catch - это не очень хорошо. Прибегайте к этому только в том случае, если точно знаете, что вам в этом месте не надо перезивать ни о чем. Но я бы там как минимум логгировал ошибку

Comment: Во вторых, если вам кажется, что метод большой - разбивайте его на несколько методов (это называется extract Method). А то, что вы делаете называется безпричинное усложнение кода.

Comment: @tym32167, это всё да, но вопрос о другом. Первое предложение: Вопрос не про то, как красиво программировать, чтобы этот вопрос не возникал, а про красивую обертку над try-catch. Но спасибо, полезно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Клюнула идейка, которая позволяет уместиться в один блок.

Использовать можно так:

```
    Try.AutoRunAction = () =>
    {
        //code block
    };
```

Вот сырая реализация:

```
    public class Try
    {
        // runs on set
        public static Action AutoRunAction
        {
            set
            {
                try { value?.Invoke(); }
                catch { }
            }
        }
    }
```

- то же самое, что из метода, но меньше скобок
- раньше был геттер, который посоветовали убрать
- можно еще назвать `AutoTryAction`
- принимаю критику

---

Пример:

```
    private static void SetAttributesNormal(DirectoryInfo dir)
    {
        AutoTryAction = () =>
        {
            foreach (var subDir in dir.GetDirectories())
            {
                SetAttributesNormal(subDir);
                AutoTryAction = () => subDir.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
            }
        };

        AutoTryAction = () =>
        {
            foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
            {
                AutoTryAction = () => file.Attributes = FileAttributes.Normal;
            }
        };
    }

    private static Action AutoTryAction
    {
        set
        {
            try { value?.Invoke(); }
            catch { }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Своеобразное решение, конечно) И да, зачем Вам геттер?

Answer (score 2):

Я предлагаю наоборот обьеденить try-catch вместе, т.к. построение фрейма для ловли ошибок считаю затратной операцией. Сделать это можно через цикл. Пусть у вас 10 случаев. Вместо `try{}catch{}` прийдется писать `case x:; break;` боюсь сомнительный выигрыш. Разве что... авто-редактор кода не будет превращать это в 5 строк.

```
int nmax = 10;
int step = 0;
while (step < nmax) 
    try { // общий try
    for (int istep = step; istep < nmax; istep++)
       switch (istep) {
         case 0:;
             break;
         case 1:;
             break;
         // .....
          }
    } catch { step++;}
```

Обвертка вроде небольшая. Считаю что повысит быстродействие если не будет исключений... но незначительно. Более компактный вариант

```
 for (int step=0;step<10;step++) try { switch (step) { 
     case 0:; break;
      //.... 
 } } catch {};
```

Уже как я понял смысла практически не имеет.

- Вариант с Try(MethodCall) - чуть более затратный по времени.
- Вариант с using - не получится реализовать... явно, ну развечто если реализовать его так-само как и предыдущий вариант `using (var x=new Try(MethodCall))` - что будет изврат. Что бы не было изврата... теоретически можно раскопать il-позицию... но на практике сделать проброс врядли выйдет.

Вариант 2. Базируясь на варианте 1, и зная [номер линии кода](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/763539/line-%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b0), можно шаманить. Но опять же, "условно". Если считать, что каждая строка выполняется один раз, то можно сделать так:

```
bool ready = false;
int step= 0;
while (!ready) try {
     if (trysafe(ref step)) {  method1; /*шаг 1*/ };
     if (trysafe(ref step)) {  method2; /*шаг 2*/};
     ready = true;
     } catch {
     };
   }

//  отсекатель
bool trysafe(int ref kkey, [CallerLineNumber] int line = -1){
   if (kkey < line ) return false;
   kkey = line;
   return true;
   }
```

При исключении, произойдет цикл, и методы которые прошли в if будут пропущены независимо от того было исключение или нет. Отсекатель можно сделать через Dictionary (будет более "умный"). Но код должен предполагать разбивку на шаги как и в предыдущем случае, но шаги можно более "вольно" располагать. Промежутков между шагами не должно быть. Вызов trysafe - должен всегда происходить в разных строках программы. Аргумент kkey можно тоже сократить, и вынести в глобальную область, в зависимости от ситуации.

P.S. Тихие исключения опасно использовать, потому что в итоге очень сложно отыскать ошибку.

Comment: Спасибо, интересная идея, но тут актуально для последовательного вызова методов, а может быть такое, что вложенность. Ну и под "красотой" может быть имел ввиду другое: не то, чтобы по времени было быстро, а чтобы выглядело в тексте кода, как будто без наворотов. Но спасибо, идея интересная!

Comment: Второй вариант - это супер! Но правда не совсем то, потому что код становится более сложным для понимания. Супер - потому, что используются интересные приемы. Может быть, за счет каких - то нетривиальных приемов можно придумать что-то интересное.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать функционального подход:

```
public readonly struct Try<T>
{
    private readonly Lazy<(T, Exception)> factory;

    public Try(Func<(T, Exception)> factory) =>
        this.factory = new Lazy<(T, Exception)>(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                return factory();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                return (default, exception);
            }
        });
}

public static class TryExtensions
{
    public static Try<TResult> SelectMany<TSource, TSelector, TResult>(
        this Try<TSource> source,
        Func<TSource, Try<TSelector>> selector,
        Func<TSource, TSelector, TResult> resultSelector) =>
            new Try<TResult>(() =>
            {
                if (source.HasException)
                {
                    return (default, source.Exception);
                }
                Try<TSelector> result = selector(source.Value);
                if (result.HasException)
                {
                    return (default, result.Exception);
                }
                return (resultSelector(source.Value, result.Value), (Exception)null);
            });

    public static Try<TSource> Try<TSource>(this TSource value) => value;

    public static Try<TResult> Select<TSource, TResult>(
        this Try<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TResult> selector) =>
            source.SelectMany(value => selector(value).Try(), (value, result) => result);

    public static Try<T> Throw<T>(
        this Exception exception) => 
            new Try<T>(() => (default, exception));

    public static Try<T> Try<T>(Func<T> function) =>
        new Try<T>(() => (function(), (Exception)null));

    public static Try<T> Catch<T, TException>(
        this Try<T> source, Func<TException, Try<T>> handler, Func<TException, bool> when = null)
        where TException : Exception =>
            new Try<T>(() =>
            {
                if (source.HasException && 
                    source.Exception is TException exception && 
                    exception != null && (
                    when == null || 
                    when(exception)))
                {
                    source = handler(exception);
                }
                return source.HasException ? (default, source.Exception) : (source.Value, (Exception)null);
            });

    public static Try<T> Catch<T>(
        this Try<T> source, 
        Func<Exception, Try<T>> handler, 
        Func<Exception, bool> when = null) =>
            Catch<T, Exception>(source, handler, when);

    public static TResult Finally<T, TResult>(
        this Try<T> source, 
        Func<Try<T>, TResult> action) => action(source);

    public static void Finally<T>(
        this Try<T> source, 
        Action<Try<T>> action) => action(source);
}
```

Пример:

```
internal static Try<int> Example(int? value)
{
    if (value == null)
    {
        return Throw<int>(new ArgumentNullException(nameof(value)));
    }
}
```

Немного про то откуда это: [Category Theory via C# Fundamentals](https://weblogs.asp.net/dixin/category-theory-via-csharp-1-fundamentals)

Видео: [uDev Tech Meetup #10: Функциональный C#](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OK8ddPZGaVs)

Comment: Здорово, спасибо! А можно пример, как этим пользоваться, а то интересно, но не сходу понятно.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ответ! После того, как почитал про syntex `(T, Exception)`, то есть, узнал про ValueTuple-s, стало понятно. Полезно, интересно. Но все равно интересно как этим лучше пользоваться.

Comment: @Andrey K., дополнил ответ